# window.open() does not work on iOS app using phone gap

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I am writing an ios app using Phonegap,
all i need in my app is that when the phonegap call the 
index.html the html page will redirect the user to my web site
the thing is that the html does not redirect the app to my site, i do not
care if the phone gap open the safari i just need it to redirect it to my site my code 
is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadlink()
    {
        window.open("www.cnn.com");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadlink()">        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your function look like this:

```
function loadlink() {
  window.location.href = "www.cnn.com";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Or even better

```
function loadlink() {
    if (typeof (window.open) == "function") {
        window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
    }
    else {
        window.location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
    }
}
```

Since Internet Explorer don't like very much with window.location.href